How to use numpad keys as shortcuts in the new versions of Android studio?
Before (e.g.g in Android studio 4.1.2) I could use numpad keys as shortcuts but now when I set numpad keys as shortcuts it doesn't work anymore. Maybe someone knows how to fix it?
